# StackOverflowError in Scalacheck without any recursion (or custom generators)

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I really wish I understood better how scalacheck works, but scarce docs help me little here:

```
property("overflow") = forAll { arr :Array[Long] => all(({
    for (lo <- 0 to arr.length * 64; hi <- lo to arr.length * 64) yield Prop(true)
}):_*)}
```

Now, I have a couple of guesses, all dubious:

- Infinite arrays, i.e. generator never terminating generating elements - but this is the default generator, so it shouldn't be an issue. Unlikely in light of the same result with my own generator.
- Evaluating the `Prop`s in non-tail recursion and failing on a large array. Again unlikely, as I tried it with small arrays.

The above code is the the simplified version I created when I thought I somehow screwed up my own generator:

```
implicit val randomBitmap = Arbitrary(for {
        size <- Gen.choose(0, 6)
        array <- Gen.buildableOfN[Array[Long], Long](size, Arbitrary.arbLong.arbitrary)
    } yield new LongBitmap(array)
)

class LongBitmap(private val arr :Array[Long]) extends AnyVal

property("overflow") = forAll { arr :LongBitmap => all(({
    for (lo <- 0 to arr.length * 64; hi <- lo to arr.length * 64) yield Prop(true)
}):_*)}
```

What gives? My scala-fu seems to have left me lately.